# Automatic differentiation with ForwardDiff in Julia

Tags: julia, automatic-differentiation

I am having some trouble using correctly the ForwardDiff package in Julia. I have managed to isolate my problem in the following chunk of code.

In short, I define the function:

```
using ForwardDiff

function likelihood(mu,X)

  N = size(X,2)

  # Calculate likelihood
  aux = zeros(N)
  for nn=1:N
    aux[nn] = exp(-0.5 * (X[:,nn]-mu)' *  (X[:,nn]-mu))[1]
  end

  # return log-likelihood
  return sum(log(aux))

end
```

I then check if the function works:

```
# Check if function works at all
X = randn(2,3) # some random data
mu = [1.0;2.0] # arbitrary mean
@show likelihood(mu,X) # works fine for me
```

I then try to obtain the gradient using:

```
ForwardDiff.gradient( ARG -> likelihood(ARG, X), mu)
```

Unfortunately this fails and I see in my screen:

> ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching
>   convert(::Type{Float64}, ::ForwardDiff.Dual{2,Float64}) This may have
>   arisen from a call to the constructor Float64(...), since type
>   constructors fall back to convert methods. Closest candidates are:
>   call{T<:AbstractFloat}(::Type{T<:AbstractFloat}, ::Real,
>   ::RoundingMode{T})   call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
>   convert(::Type{Float64}, ::Int8)   ...  in likelihood at none:10  in
>   anonymous at none:1

What am I doing wrong? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: In further investigation, I have managed to reproduce this error in an even simpler version of the code above. I have opened an issue in the ForwardDiff github. I will post a comment here too, once I get a response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was just informed that this was a careless mistake on my side, though a bit hard to spot to the untrained eye.

The error is at the call to zeros:

```
aux = zeros(N)
```

Changing this to

```
aux = zeros(eltype(mu),N)
```

solves the problem. Hope this is useful to others.